# Some way to perform a TrimAfterLast() in Fidder Script

Tags: json, string, fiddler

There is the very helpful Utilities.TrimBeforeLast() function in Fiddler script. However, I really need to perform a Utilities.Trim**After**Last(StringVar, "}") to remove the extra characters after a JSON object i've captured. 
Is there any way I could produce this equivalent result with fiddlerscript?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

FiddlerScript allows you to use the entire .NET Framework, which offers many different functions for processing strings.

In this case, you'd probably want to use something like:

```
var sMyString = "whatever}junk";
var iX = sMyString.LastIndexOf('}');
sMyString = sMyString.Substring(0, iX);
```